# Symfony lock duplicate key value violates unique constraint when two process run on the same resource

Tags: php, symfony

When two process run at the same time and lock the same resource, i got an error message from my postgres logs.

Duplicate key value violates unique constraint "lock_keys_pkey"

more details about the error

[image: 1]

this is the code i use

[image: 2]

Someone has an idea why this happen ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Comment: Please copy the code block into your question, instead of adding a screenshot. If you are not sure about formatting, don't worry, others can step in and help with that afterwards. Regarding your question, isn't that exactly what you want from a lock? What is the behavior you expected instead? If both processes read the resource, you might want to look at [the shared locks section in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html#shared-locks)